# How can I pass a date parameter in an arbitrary format using C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to pass the date parameter from C# like this:

```
2010-11-30 15:54:20.047
```

I googled it many ways, but none of the options gave me a solution. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: "Not able to" is not the same thing as "I don't know how to".

Answer (score 5):

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Depending on your exact requirements, you may wish to use the `ToString` overload that takes an `IFormatProvider`:

```
dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Beware of the `:` character in date/time format strings: it represents the [time separator character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#timeSeparator), which can resolve to something other than `:` (e.g. to `.` under Italian locales). Better surround it with single quotes to avoid that possibility: `"yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss.fff"`.

Comment: Kent Boogaart->still i am getting datetime as 12/31/2010 how i written

Comment: DateTime datetime=DateTime.Now;

Comment: dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");

Comment: @Jims: what are you doing with the result of `ToString()`? Calling `ToString` won't modify the underlying `DateTime`. You need to use the return value of `ToString`.

Comment: @Jims: You have to assign the result of the `ToString` call to another variable. It does not modify the underlying `DateTime` object that you call it on. For example: `string current = dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more generic listing if you decide you want some other format.
http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/